# protocol method

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am struggling to apply a workaround I found regarding UIWebView accepting tap-events. Source:

http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

. The author reminds the reader that he has to implement a '-userDidTapWebView' method, which is declared in a protocol. I don't know where and how to implement this method in order to obtain the desired result. So, I am kindly asking you for help. Thanks in advance for the patience of looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@protocol TapDetectingWindowDelegate
- (void)userDidTapWebView:(id)tapPoint;
@end
```

This declares a *protocol* (interfaces in Java/C#/D term), which the *adopting class* must implement the content of the protocol (i.e. the `-userDidTapWebView:` method.)

Later in the page,

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController<TapDetectingWindowDelegate>
```

The `<…>` means the WebViewController class is *adopting* the TapDetectingWindowDelegate protocol. Therefore, this class must fulfill the restrictions imposed by this adoption, i.e. the WebViewController must implement `-userDidTapWebView:`.

The implementation is done in the `@implementation`, e.g.

```
@implementation WebViewController
- (void)userDidTapWebView:(id)tapPoint {
    NSLog(@"User tapped web view at point %@.", tapPoint);
}
@end
```